# How to extract specific lines from a .txt file in R and store it in a vector

Tags: r, regex

I am working with a transcript of a show and would like to extract the text of each speaker and store it into its own vector. The data looks like this -

```
BOB: blah blah blah blah

TRUDY: blah blah

BOB: you get the idea however some of the text  is on a new line like 

this so I don't know how to extract it to the correct vector

TRUDY: blah blah blah
```

.. and so on.

I imagine I need to use a combination of readLines and grep however I am not sure how to implement it.

Comment: What do you want the output to look like? Are the different names always in that format at the beginning?

Comment: Is it safe to assume that newlines would split your text into lines of different speakers?

Comment: Yes the names are always in that format, I would like the output for each speaker to be a vector containing everything that speaker has said.

Comment: yes the new lines split the speakers. However sometimes there is multiple lines from the one speaker and those lines have a new line between them.

Comment: I think this is sort of what I am looking for https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21076/how-to-show-lines-after-each-grep-match-until-other-specific-match

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem. Not sure this is exactly the output you need, but it should give you a good idea.

```
text <- 
"BOB: blah blah blah blah
TRUDY: bleh bleh
BOB: you get the idea however some of the text is on a new line like 
this so I don't know how to extract it to the correct vector
TRUDY: bleh bleh bleh
BOB: Durrh!!!"

# Replace line feeds with spaces
text <- gsub(pattern = "\\n", replacement = " ", x = text)

# Split string into words to find alternations of BOB / TRUDY
who <- strsplit(x = text, split = " ")[[1]]
who <- who[who %in% c("BOB:", "TRUDY:")] 

# Split string using BOB: and TRUDY:
dialog <- strsplit(x = text, split = "(BOB: )|(TRUDY: )", perl = TRUE)[[1]][-1]

# create the two final vectors
bob <- trimws(dialog[which(who=="BOB:")])
trudy <- trimws(dialog[which(who=="TRUDY:")])
```

### RESULTS

```
> bob
[1] "blah blah blah blah"                                                                                                          
[2] "you get the idea however some of the text is on a new line like  this so I don't know how to extract it to the correct vector"
[3] "Durrh!!!"                                                                                                                     
> trudy
[1] "bleh bleh"      "bleh bleh bleh"
```

Comment: I like the use of gsub here

Comment: I know this was some time ago, however I am revisiting this and it works perfectly. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `text` contains your data. Then try this

```
text <- readlines("data.txt")
pos <- which(stringr::word(text,1,1) %in% c("BOB:","TRUDY:"))
mapply(function(x,y){do.call(paste,as.list(text[x:y-1]))},pos,c(pos[-1],length(text)+1))
```